# TypeError: Error resolving module specifier

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6

I am getting `TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: d3` when trying to import d3.js library. The project uses npm and the error has been encountered in Firefox.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <header>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>D3</title>
  </header>

  <body>
    <div id="svg"></div>
    <script src="./index.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
```

Comment: The answer by @hurried-helpful does answer your question.

Answer (score 5):

Bare import specifiers like "d3" are still not supported in browsers. Import specifiers should be either an absolute or a relative path to the file. For example, `import * as d3 from "./d3.js";`

Relative path specifiers should start with `/`, `./`, or `../`.

Comment: There is [a shim](https://github.com/guybedford/es-module-shims) to add support, though.