# Loading module was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type

Tags: javascript, firefox, npm, ecmascript-6

I am getting `Loading module from “http://localhost:3000/d3.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“”)` when trying to import d3.js library. The project uses npm and the error has been encountered in Firefox.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <header>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>D3</title>
  </header>

  <body>
    <div id="svg"></div>
    <script src="./index.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import * as d3 from "./d3.js";
```

Comment: did you try using the cdn `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>``

Comment: What's the MIME the header is returning for this HTTP request? You can check that in your Network tab (F12). What web server are you using? Have you checked that is sending the correct MIME types?

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález It is x-unknown-content-type. I use the web server https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server . How can I make sure it is sending the correct MIME types?

Comment: @HachimiAhmedAmine Yeah but then I would always get "d3.xyz" is undefined.

Comment: i don't understand why it's imported like that in the same level as index.js you have a d3.js file ? if you are using npm so i guess  you have  node_modules it should be `import * as d3 from "d3" `;

Comment: @HachimiAhmedAmine I tried that, but then I get TypeError https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60496022/typeerror-error-resolving-module-specifier

Comment: can you provide more details the code structure and what are you using to serve that index.html in localhost ?

Comment: @HachimiAhmedAmine Because browsers also accept `import` like you do in nodejs. He is loading the file in the browser, not in nodejs, so you need to specify the relative path. There's no `node_modules` in the browser.

Comment: @PeterJiang it depends on the implementation of the server. You should go to the developer website (usually its GitHub) and follow documentation, read the source code to see how they implement MIME types and such. Is not a 2-minutes-fix. By the way, by reading other users source code you'll learn a lot actually.